# how to rewrite index from an array of object from a json file on javascript

Tags: javascript

so Basically

I have a `content.json` file

```
[
  {
    "content1": {
      "link": {
        "title": "lorem lorem",
        "url": "http://localhost"
      },
      "description": "lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem"
    }
  },
  {
    "content2": {
      "title": "loremloremloremloremloremlorem",
      "thumbnail": {
        "caption": "loremloremloremlorem",
        "image": {
          "desktop": "https://via.placeholder.com/900x500",
          "tablet": "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400",
          "mobile": "https://via.placeholder.com/320x320"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the code below works but as you can see I have to declare a new variable for each parent object,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import jsonContent from "./data/content.json";
import Test1 from "./components/Test1.js";
import Test2 from "./components/Test2.js";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const data1 = jsonContent.find(item => item.content1);
  const data2 = jsonContent.find(item => item.content2);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test1 content={data1.content1} />
      <Test2 content={data2.content2} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

what I'm trying to do it's just get the data like

```
const data = jsonContent.map(item => item.content1);

console.log(data.content1) //output content1 object
console.log(data.content2) //output content2 object
```

so I can declera once and pass though any component like

```
<Test1 content={data.content1} />
<Test2 content={data.content2} />
```

I also created a codesandbox
so you can test

https://codesandbox.io/s/nk70pw8lpl

thanks...

Comment: *"just return an something like `[{content: Object},{content2}]`"* That isn't clear. What is the exact, complete structure you want?

Comment: *"I also created a codesandbox so you can test"* Please use on-site Stack Snippets, not offsite resources, for your runnable examples. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That prevents your accidentally leaving out important details, and makes it really easy for people to help you by clicking the "Copy Snippet to Answer" button and editing.

Comment: Why does the original JSON have keys like `"contentX"` in the first place? It wraps everything else, and you have an array anyway, so why not put the objects directly inside the array?

Comment: content.json is an array. You can access "content1" and "content2" by array indextes(0 and 1)...

Comment: Do the 'content1' and content2' properties have any meaning? I would have expected the json file to look more like `[{name:"content1",title:"something"},{name:"content2",title:"something"}]` so you can just do a simple loop over the json instead of having to create seperate variables and hooks for everything you want to add. That would be easier to maintain and just remove your problem altogether.

Comment: @Shilly I know it looks a bit odd, ideally I wanted to named same as the component... if I have a <blog> component I can just look for the [{blog:{}, xxx }]..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the React guide link...

Comment: @Macrogomesr My point is that content1 and content2 should not be properties, but values. Then you can use something like `data.map( component => <{component.name} content="{component.content}/> )` ( not correct syntax ), so that adding another component to the JSON file automatically includes it in the app, instead of you having to open the app.js file again and add `const data3 = data.find(...)...`.

Comment: This entire question is based on a bad initial structure of that JSON file. If you want to name stuff appropriately, use something like `{ "blog": [...], "pages": [...] }` where each array contains the blog entry / page data. Then you can simply map over `jsonContent.blog` without having to worry about sub keys.

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://codesandbox.io/s/73ypq45426

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert this into one single object data, you have loop through all entries and take the first key and put that in another object. Below is the logic doing the same thing -

```
let json = [
  {
    "content1": {
      "link": {
        "title": "lorem lorem",
        "url": "http://localhost"
      },
      "description": "lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem"
    }
  },
  {
    "content2": {
      "title": "loremloremloremloremloremlorem",
      "thumbnail": {
        "caption": "loremloremloremlorem",
        "image": {
          "desktop": "https://via.placeholder.com/900x500",
          "tablet": "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400",
          "mobile": "https://via.placeholder.com/320x320"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

let data = {};

json.forEach(row => {
  let keys = Object.keys(row);
  data[keys[0]] = row[keys[0]];
});

console.log(data);
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/Pau2hir1s

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array#reduce to transform your array of objects to just an object.

```js
const data = [{"content1":{"link":{"title":"lorem lorem","url":"http://localhost"},"description":"lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem"}},{"content2":{"title":"loremloremloremloremloremlorem","thumbnail":{"caption":"loremloremloremlorem","image":{"desktop":"https://via.placeholder.com/900x500","tablet":"https://via.placeholder.com/600x400","mobile":"https://via.placeholder.com/320x320"}}}}];

const res = data.reduce((a,c)=>{
  const key = Object.keys(c).shift();
  a[key] = c[key];
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```

Verbose solution using `for`:

```js
const data = [{"content1":{"link":{"title":"lorem lorem","url":"http://localhost"},"description":"lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem"}},{"content2":{"title":"loremloremloremloremloremlorem","thumbnail":{"caption":"loremloremloremlorem","image":{"desktop":"https://via.placeholder.com/900x500","tablet":"https://via.placeholder.com/600x400","mobile":"https://via.placeholder.com/320x320"}}}}];

const res = {};
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  const item = data[i];
  const key  = Object.keys(item).shift();
  res[key] = item[key];
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think you've guessed at the OP's goal better than I have. But I have to say I'm not a fan of using reduce when the accumulator never changes. https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's actually not the first time I've heard about this. However, I don't see another possible solution without having an external variable. Thanks for the twitter post, it makes sense. for loops seem to be underrated.

Comment: Yeah, I'd just use a loop. Having the variable isn't a problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The format of that JSON file is unfortunate. I'm going to assume here that each object in the outermost array will have at most **one** property (`content1`, `content2`, etc.), and that it refers to an object.

If so, once you've parsed the JSON, reformatting things is fairly straightforward:

```
const reformatted = data.map(entry => entry[Object.keys(entry)[0]]);
```

That gets the object that the one property of each of those object wrappers has and puts it in the result array. Then you just use the objects in that resulting array directly.

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "content1": {
      "link": {
        "title": "lorem lorem",
        "url": "http://localhost"
      },
      "description": "lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem"
    }
  },
  {
    "content2": {
      "title": "loremloremloremloremloremlorem",
      "thumbnail": {
        "caption": "loremloremloremlorem",
        "image": {
          "desktop": "https://via.placeholder.com/900x500",
          "tablet": "https://via.placeholder.com/600x400",
          "mobile": "https://via.placeholder.com/320x320"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

const reformatted = data.map(entry => entry[Object.keys(entry)[0]]);

console.log(reformatted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```